# Implement Correlation Id in the REST service application

Tags: java, spring, logback

We were planning to implement Correlation id concept for our rest service application. So i just gone through some tutorials and i got some idea on Correlation id concept.

**1) Can we implement it through logging framework ?**

**2) How effectively the log file data with correlation id is to be formed so that it will be helpful for debugging and informational purposes.**

Comment: Yes it can be implemented using a logging frameworks just append the corellation id when logging information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be implemented using a centralized logging framework just append the corellation id when logging.

To effectively use the corellation id for distributed tracing try using frameworks like zipkin (https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin)